# Appmaker Input Form, change options based on earlier dropdown choices

Tags: google-app-maker

Hypothetical:

Say i'm having someone order a cake and they choose vanilla or chocolate, and then they have to choose a frosting

```
if vanilla: strawberry or buttercream   

if chocolate: mocha, dark chocolate or buttercream.
```

Right now the frosting value in the data model can accept all four options, so all four show up in the dropdown.

a) is there a way to change the binding for the second dropdown after the first is chosen?

Comment: If you have your cake choices in a data model and also your frosting choices, then I would set up a relation between the cake type to the frosting type and then see if you can change the binding on the second dropdown options to `@datasources.CakeType.relations.Frosting.items`. No guarantee this will work, I have not had the time myself to work on solving dependent selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you set the dropdown "possible value" options in the data source and you have those fields as just string fields in your table.

the quick and dirty way to do this is go to the Cake drop down and on the Property Editor>Events>OnValueChange select Custom Action and use this Code

```
if(widget.value==="Vanilla"){
   widget.root.descendants.Field.options = ['Strawberry','Buttercream'];
}else if (widget.value === "Chocolate"){
  widget.root.descendants.Field.options = ['Mocha','Dark Chocolate','Buttercream'];
}
```

"Field" here is replaced with the name of the dropdown box for your frostings

also go to the property editor of the frostings dropdown and delete everything in the options field there.

Comment: great! my use case is more complex than this but this gives me a great start

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without having the data saved in any datasource. Simply do the following...

Suppose the first dropdown is named **primaryDropdown** and the second dropdown is called **secondaryDropdown**. In the **primaryDropdown** options set the following:

```
["Vanilla", "Chocolate"]
```

Also, make sure to uncheck the option **allowNull** and on the **onAttach** event handler, place the following:

```
widget.value = "Vanilla";
```

Now we move on to the **secondaryDropdown**. Here, we will do a binding so place the following in the options value:

```
getAvailableOpts(@widget.root.descendants.primaryDropdown.value)
```

In the client script, we need to make sure that function exists so please paste the following in any client script:

```
function getAvailableOpts(primaryValue){

  var options;

  switch(primaryValue){
    case "Vanilla":
      options =["Strawberry","Buttercream"];
      break;
    case "Chocolate":
      options = ["Mocha","Dark Chocolate","Buttercream"];
      break;
    default:
      options = [];
  }

  return options;

}
```

From here, you are good; However we can still make it better. For that, make sure to also uncheck the **allowNull** option for the **secondaryDropdown** and then we need to add some logic in the **onValueChange** event handler of the **primaryDropdown**.

```
widget.root.descendants.secondaryDropdown.value = widget.root.descendants.secondaryDropdown.options[0];
```

References:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#dropdown
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#bindings
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#use_scripts_in_binding_expressions

Comment: This is a better answer

Comment: @Morfinismo have you by chance solved this for dynamic data? I’m just thinking especially for such items as here, where menu items along with sub selections might change, one would have to hard code this in every time whereas users with certain roles could enter new records along with related sub items.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I have indeed. There are several approaches to be honest. It all depends on the specific use case. Might be client scripting, might be server scripting or simply working with relations.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve for a similar situation and created an additional table to serve as a lookup.

I have a drop down for `CATEGORY` with possible options set on the field in the main data source.

Then I have a second table with 2 Columns: `CATEGORY`, and `SUB_CATEGORY`.

On the entry form I have options for the `SUB_CATEGORY` drop down set to `SUB_CATEGORY` on the `CATEGORY_MATRIX` lookup table.

Then for an onValueEdit event on the `CATEOGRY` drop down I have a script to reload the `CATEGORY_MATRIX` table source based on the value of the `CATEGORY` drop down in the query so when the `CATEGORY` is selected only valid `SUB_CATEGORY` options are shown in the second drop down.

```
var datasource = app.datasources.CATEGORY_MATRIX 
datasource.query.filters.CATEGORY._equals = newValue;
datasource.load();
```

There may be more efficient ways to do this but the benefit is I could create another form page and dynamically add new combos so there isn't any required code change as new combos are needed.