# Dependent dropdown in table columns / widget

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to have dependent dropdown in table columns? Example in table A I have ColumnA1 & ColumnB1, both have dropdowns, B1 dropdown values should be filtered based on Value selected in A1. Any help on this is really appreciated.

Example: 
I have a page with Tabular data entry, few columns in table has Dropdown attached. I want to filter data in dropdown based on value selected in previous column in same row. 
I am unable to find any code example in Appmaker help or in templates. 
Can someone please help me to achieve dependent dropdown in Table widget?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appmaker Input Form, change options based on earlier dropdown choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781139/appmaker-input-form-change-options-based-on-earlier-dropdown-choices)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by attaching an event property to A1.

For example, on dropdown A1's `onValueChange` event:

```
updateB1(newValue);
```

In a client-side script, write the following:

```
function updateB1(valueOfA1) {
  var widgetB1 = app.pages.<page>.descendants.DropdownB1;

  // Re-define dropdown B1's options - your filter goes here
  widgetB1.options = ["array","of","options"];
  widgetB1.names = ["array","of","names"]; // this one is optional
}
```

All the logic for what values appear in B1, depending on A1's value, would be in the script.